# How to automatically fill a Model-Form field with a default value obtained from a variable?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, modelform

I am using ModelForm and i want to populate my dataset_id field with an initial value that will come from the "pid" variable passed in the arguement. I ve tried something and attaching that code but its not working

**views.py**

```
def home(request, pid):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = DelegateForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            p = form.save()
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:


         # Here I want to pass the value of "pid" to the dataset_id field so that when it renders it is populated with the value in the pid variable
        form = DelegateForm(initial={'dataset_id': pid})



    return render(request, 'add_delegate.html', {'dform': form, 'uid': pid})
```

**models.py**

```
class Delegate(models.Model):
    dataset_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_path = models.CharField(max_length=2083, null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DelegateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Delegate
        fields = ['dataset_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        widgets = {
            'dataset_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

**template.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<form action="/success/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ dform.dataset_id.label_tag }}</label>
        {{ dform.dataset_id }}
        <label>{{ dform.name.label_tag }}</label>
        {{ dform.name }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: where you are using `ModelForm`? I didn't see here

Comment: Should the pid be the id of the object, the dataset_id or something else?

Comment: pid is a unique that is being passed on to my def home method from another view function . pid is filled with a 4 digit unique number everytime it is passed

Comment: i basically want the pid value from the def home parameter and then use this value to populate the dataset_id field automatically with that value

Answer (score 0):

There was some function clashing in my code , and i separated them so now i have got my solution

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the pid should be used as parameter in the signature of the url, so that it will be passed to the corresponding view (the `home` view in this case). Your urls file will contain

```
path('home_path/<int:pid>', views.home, name='a')
```

and than in the views file:

```
def home(request, pid):
    ...
```